# Tool to compare images on Windows

Tags: windows, image

Any command line tools on Windows that can give metrics value for 2 images comparison?
Tried ImageMagick, but it gives error if the images are not the same size.

Comment: How about resizing the images to be the same size and then doing the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perceptual Image Diff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/) might be something?

Comment: I think it's easy to find a .dll from google and place it into system32. Correct me if I'm wrong.